# left+right aligned text in UITableView cell, breaks when table is scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My goal is to display 2 strings in the same cell, one of them left aligned and the other right aligned. The code I have attached does just that in a table view, however it breaks when you scroll up/down. I need this to work in a table that can scroll. Someone had mentioned using CustomUITableViewCells instead of my current method, can anyone point me to an example of this?

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            UILabel *rank = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 20];
            [rank setTag:5];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:rank];
            [rank release];

            UILabel *item = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 5, 220, 20];
            [item setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
            [item setTag:6];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:item];
            [item release];
        }

        UILabel *rank = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        UILabel *item = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];

        rank.text = @"leftside";
        item.text = @"rightside";
    }

Any ideas and thoughts greatly appricated, thanks for lookin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is because of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. While the cell is being re-used, and when you scroll up and down it will cause major problems as labels are being added as subviews to the cells and **they do not have the properties of the cell.** However, if you use the `cell.textLabel` as your label, it would not cause problems like the one you are facing now, but you cannot add more than one label.

You have two solutions for this.

1. In your case, you need to stop using the same `cellIdentifier` for each and use different identifiers for each cells so that they do not get reused. This would be helpful if you have a very small number of rows in the `tableView` or it would turn out to be inefficient.
2. A better solution would be to **subclass** `UITableViewCell` and add those two labels in it's code, and then use that UITableViewCell with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. This is just a small amount of work, and you get to re-use cells. This would be very helpful if you have a large number of rows in your tableview.

   Go through [THIS TUTORIAL](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/) to learn on how to subclass `UITableViewCell` with 2 labels.

   You will need to work with the method, `- (void)layoutSubviews` and add those labels to your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

And remember to reference this `customUITableViewCell` instead of the default uitableviewcell when you are loading up the `tableView`. Your `UILabels` will not be messed up anymore.

[Another reference](https://github.com/effectiveprogramming/ep-iphone/wiki/uitableviewcell).

Comment: Legolas, huge thanks for your help. I was able to get everything working as I wanted using a subclass UITableViewCell, which also streamlined my design quite a bit. The link you provided to the iphone noob tutorial really helped it click for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom `UITableViewCell`. The easiest way is to just download a sample project, and copy and paste to see how you set up a custom cell. [This is](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) a good tutorial with a sample project included. You can use `if (indexPath.row == int)` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to determine which cells should be the standard ones, and which should be your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have paste the same code that you have posted and I got 2 compiler error mentioning the **)** is missing at the allocation of UILable and as I have clear it out, its compiled and started successfully.

The only exception and crash I have faced and that was due to the datasource method is not returning any cell. And that is also missing in given code.

Beside that, the code is working perfectly at my end and not having a single crash even though I scrolled many times.

So, just verify your code again or there should be another problem regarding datasource provided by array and also check the number of rows in section.